# Is it possible (how?) to remove the gap before the line numbers in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, when line numbers option is enabled for the text editor it creates a gap that can hold about 5 figures number in it. How do I adjust that "gap" only to the size of the maximum number of lines currently in the file?

[image: Visual Studio 2012 editor unnecessary gap][image: Visual Studio 2012 editor without the gap]

Comment: No you can't unfortunately. Why the need to do that anyway?

Comment: That allows me to have more space when working with larger font sizes and on screens that have low resolution, and still be able see the line numbers